# My Question is In if Display inline then we can not use margin bottom?

Tags: html, css, anchor, display, displaytag

Here `<a>` tag has `display: inline` so `margin-bottom` can not apply but when I use `display: block` then it works.

Why can't I define a `margin-bottom` on an `inline` element?

---

#### `display: inline;` with `margin-bottom: 1rem`:

```css
a {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a>Nunc dolor est, placerat eget ullamcorper ut, tempor sed est. In sagittis posuere fermentum. Curabitur lorem leo, lobortis vitae varius id, finibus eu risus.</a> Donec ligula nibh, eleifend a eros sed, vestibulum viverra felis. Donec ante lacus, laoreet nec purus ac, suscipit cursus tellus. Maecenas a nibh finibus, elementum tellus sed, bibendum urna. <a>Mauris quis blandit erat, et fermentum felis. Pellentesque fringilla purus elit, consectetur malesuada lorem tempus at</a>. Sed sit amet placerat mauris. Vivamus in malesuada nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Vestibulum non urna vitae est luctus viverra fermentum a orci. Etiam vitae dignissim risus. Nunc urna quam, pellentesque et neque vel, tincidunt aliquet lacus. Donec lacus magna, aliquam at neque venenatis, placerat imperdiet magna. Sed iaculis aliquet enim eu suscipit. Aliquam maximus pretium mollis. <a>Fusce bibendum orci est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam suscipit blandit arcu a gravida. Integer pellentesque auctor commodo</a>.</p>
```

---

#### `display: block;` with `margin-bottom: 1rem`:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a>Nunc dolor est, placerat eget ullamcorper ut, tempor sed est. In sagittis posuere fermentum. Curabitur lorem leo, lobortis vitae varius id, finibus eu risus.</a> Donec ligula nibh, eleifend a eros sed, vestibulum viverra felis. Donec ante lacus, laoreet nec purus ac, suscipit cursus tellus. Maecenas a nibh finibus, elementum tellus sed, bibendum urna. <a>Mauris quis blandit erat, et fermentum felis. Pellentesque fringilla purus elit, consectetur malesuada lorem tempus at</a>. Sed sit amet placerat mauris. Vivamus in malesuada nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Vestibulum non urna vitae est luctus viverra fermentum a orci. Etiam vitae dignissim risus. Nunc urna quam, pellentesque et neque vel, tincidunt aliquet lacus. Donec lacus magna, aliquam at neque venenatis, placerat imperdiet magna. Sed iaculis aliquet enim eu suscipit. Aliquam maximus pretium mollis. <a>Fusce bibendum orci est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam suscipit blandit arcu a gravida. Integer pellentesque auctor commodo</a>.</p>
```

Comment: HTML elements with `display: inline;` are not rendered as 2D rectangles (whereas `block` content is). Instead, `inline` content exists as runs of text _within_ a parent block. A run of text cannot have a bottom margin because _it doesn't have a single flat bottom edge_ for the margin to be attached to. Just add `outline: 1px solid blue;` to your rule to see why.

Comment: I suggest you to learn about inline, inline-block, block and box-model. That will do you good as they're basics.

Comment: @Dai Thank you , your comment is helpful.

Comment: @SandeepC.Nath Thank you , I will use reference w3chool or mdn which is better?

Comment: @PriyanshPatel MDN is one of the best resources, as well as https://web.dev - but **avoid** w3schools: they are not authoritative and have a poor track-record of giving really bad advice (e.g. insecure programming practices, etc) - MDN and web.dev are operated by Mozilla and Google respectively, both of which are browser vendors.